# How to get stripe card number, cvc and expiry date from the react stripe PaymentElement

Tags: stripe-payments, react-stripe

I have a question for you. How can I access the card details, like the last number of cards, expiry date, and CVC from the PaymentElement? I am using the `@stripe/react-stripe-js` package here. Here are the checkout form code:

```
 <form ref={connectRef} id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <PaymentElement
    id="payment-element"
    options={{
      layout: 'accordion',
    }}   
  />  
</form>
```

Can we get the card details from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payment method information collected using PaymentElement gets tokenized by Stripe for security and safety reasons.

When the information gets tokenized, it creates a [PaymentMethod](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object) object. You can retrieve the PaymentMethod object using the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/retrieve) and look at the `card` parameter to get last 4 and expiry.

I don't believe Stripe API returns cvc as that could have security implications.

Comment: Thanks, man! So from the backend, we can get the card number and expiry as well, right?

Comment: You won't get the full card number, but you can get last 4 digits & expiry yes.

 In order to handle raw card information (like 16 digit card number), you need to be PCI compliant. There's no way to get the full number via elements. The API might return that info but you'd need to request an exemption from Stripe and provide proof of PCI compliance afaik